# Oracle how to select and update one field value and insert records quickly

Tags: sql, oracle

We have the below scenario:

1. create table

   ```
   create table tt (id number, name varchar2(30), note varchar2(4));
   insert into tt values (1,'AC','m');
   insert into tt values (2,'Test','f');
   ```
2. we want to select the records from table tt and insert another record by updating one field value:

   ```
   INSERT INTO tt SELECT id, 'x1', note FROM tt where id=1;
   ```

As our table has many columns and we would like to find one way doing the above things **without listing all the columns names** in the step2's sql.
Is there any way can help that?

Comment: It seems that you can use `MERGE`..

Comment: You have to specify the source and target columns, unless they are guaranteed to be identical, in which case you can `select *`. But how often are two tables guaranteed to have the same columns, in the same order? Rarely, I would think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many ways to get your response.

I will try to explain to you the first one which will occur me now.
I wish you work in version 12c+.
If that is the case:

You have a beautiful function name **LISTAGG**.

In addition, you have the table **[DBA | ALL | SOURCE ]_TAB_COLUMNS**.

*If you are not working in 12c+ you must concatenate the fields of all_tab_columns into a VARCHAR2 query like:

```
CURSOR my_cursor IS SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE';
```

You can obviously order it.

```
...
BEGIN
  FOR cur IN my_cursor LOOP
    v_fields := v_fields || ',' cur.COLUMN_NAME;
  END LOOP;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ' || v_fields || ' FROM MY_TABLE';
END;
```

I am not sure but in v_field you may remove the last comma.
*

If you can Access to **LISTAGG**.

It is so easy.

```
SELECT LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_ID) INTO v_fields
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = <MY_TABLE>;
```

You can ORDER for anything, even just replace all the ORDERs parenthesis by (NULL), but not empty.
Where v_field must be like VARCHAR2(2000)

Now, finally. You need some array or collection that has the list of fields which you want to modify.
For example, if you have like...:

```
v_field := 'col1, col2, col3, col3 ... coln'
```

and array `v_varray := myvarray('col1', 'col3', colx);`

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..v_varray.COUNT LOOP
    v_field := REPLACE(v_field, v_varray(i), v_array(i) * <MY_MODIFICATION>)
  END LOOP;
END;
```

With this method, You must detect your critical fields.
You must work with VARCHARS.

I wish to help you.
If you need more detail contact me.

Regards.